# Python install module from repo v. locally

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to install a homegrown package that will be used , but python package installation is still a bit of a quagmire for me, and I haven't gotten this to work.

I created a package using `setup.py sdist`, which I uploaded to a repository

I am trying to install my package on another machine.  I tried three methods, each time on an entirely clean machine.  But none are doing what I want them to.

**Method 1**
`easy_install http://mysite/mypkg.zip`

RESULT: `mypkg.egg` gets added to \Python27\Lib\site-packages.  But none of my folder structure is there

**Method 2** 
`pip install http://mysite/mypkg.zip`

RESULT: two folders, `mypkg` and `mypkg-1.0-py2.7.egg-info`, get added to Python27\Lib\site-packages.  All of the files seem to be there.  But when I got to import or run nosetests on the folder, I get all sorts of import errors that reference mypkg modules.  I have played with PATH and PYTHONPATH to get all variations of including the folder, but nothing has worked.

**Method 3**

1. download .zip
2. extract locally
3. add folder to PATH
4. run `easy_install .` in the local dir

RESULT: unpacks pkg locally.  When I run nosetests on this folder, everything runs as expected.

Thing is, I don't want each user to have to do all of the steps in Method 3.  I will eventually be running nosetests in a .bat file that does various things with the output. I don't want every user to have to modify the .bat file to indicate where the testsuite is located.  Which is why Python27\Lib\site-packages appealed to me.

Any insight as to why these three methods behave so differently would be very helpful!